# If a person regrets and doesn't asks forgiveness for his sins will Allah forgive him?

Tags: forgiveness

I read a hadith somewhere on this forum "Regret is repentance." I don't know the isnad of it. Does this mean if I commit a sin major or minor and then regret and feel sorrow on doing it and hope Allah will forgive me?. Should I hope Allah would forgive me without asking forgiveness because I have regret of it and feel sorrow because of the sin both major and minor. Kindly please explain this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically (The question Is), If a person commits a sin "Major or Minor" and "Regrets It" but "Doesn't ask for forgiveness", Will "Allah (SWT) forgive the person (Even If they regret the Sin)"?

Well you'd first need to start by "Not committing the same sin again and making a firm oath not to commit and/or abstain from said sin" (In the future), that would be a start.

Now (Regret) as far as the sin goes Is (Great), as "If you didn't "Regret the sin" (That would be a problem). As far as "Not asking for forgiveness" and "If Allah (SWT) would forgive you" (Even though you haven't asked for It). That's really an odd question, I mean "You're regretting the Sin (Correct)"? So "Why not Just ask "Allah (SWT) to forgive you for that which you're already regretting and making a conscience effort to not repeat again"?

As far as "Not having to ask for forgiveness and being forgiven for the Sin goes", I really (Can't say this or that) as (I can't seem to find a Hadith to answer the question) and can only Judge based on my (Very Limited understanding of the Quran).

“And Allah has the most excellent and perfect names, **so worship and invoke Him by them”** (Al-A’raaf ,7:180

“**And perform Salaat, at the two ends of the day and in some hours of the night [i.e. the five compulsory Salaat].**” (Hud 11:114).

“Say: O My slaves who have transgressed against themselves (by committing evil deeds and sins)! Despair not of the Mercy of Allah, verily, **Allah forgives all sins. Truly, He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.**” (Surah Az-Zumar 39:53)

The way "I" understand this (Is as such), In order to pray "You must say the Surah's/Ayats loud enough for yourself to hear the words being utter'd". Now you're not asking about "Making a Dua" (After Salah) "In your head" but are Just stating "Will Allah (SWT) forgive me for a sin (Without asking for forgiveness) because you have "Regret for the sin", and I'm not gonna speak for "Allah (SWT)" as that Is "HIS choice (To forgive HIS Slave or not)" but again (Why Isn't HIS slave Just asking him), after Salah, during his slaves "Dua" and "Ensuring that his (MAKER) does forgive him"? That Is what I'd like to know.

Answer (score -1):

Stop commiting sin and start praying , asking of forgiveness to God is the best cure to your problem than recieving some advice from people., because some people they can advice but its only by thier knowledge but the advice from Allah you can easily feel the fifference betwen people and Allah.

Many of us are praying and calling God but the truth they might not sure who are really thier God.

Seek ye the kingdom of God and his righteousness, ask a forgiveness and be a habit of praying.

May Allah bless you... Allah ho Akbar.